# Can neutrinos cause $^{14}\rm C\to\,^{14} N$ beta-decay?

Tags: radiation, neutrinos

I half-heard in a lecture that radiocarbon beta-decay is caused by neutrinos passing close to the nuclei & weakly interacting with one of the carbon neutrons, flipping it to a proton and producing an electron. Half-heard as I said but something along those lines.

I hitherto had the understanding that beta-decay was stochastic and independent of conditions. The question is is this a real thing?  Is $^{14}\rm C\to\,^{14} N$  dependent on neutrino bombardment?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. To my understanding β- decay increases the atomic number by one so it is n -> p. β+ decay decrease the number by one so it is p -> n.

Comment: Oh, I misread the statement. I thought you said $p\to e^-$. Guess I looked over the $n\to p$ *just* before that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core reaction would be
$$ n + \nu \longrightarrow p + e^- \,,$$
which respects all the necessary conservation laws (it's diagram is, after all, a rotation of the usual beta decay diagram).

I am not aware of a measurement of this particular process, but 
$$ {}^{37}\mathrm{Cl} + \nu \longrightarrow {}^{37}\mathrm{Ar} + e^- $$
(which obviously has the same underlying process) was the basis of t[he Homestake Mine experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homestake_experiment) which so famously pointed out the solar neutrino deficit.

The only really question to ask is about the rate (given the known neutrino fluxes how does the induced reaction compare to the spontaneous beta decay)? Without actually having done a calculation I believe the induced rate to be many orders of magnitude lower than the spontaneous rate. (Just imagine how hot a sample of pure carbon-14 with the same number of moles as the Homestake target would be ...)

Comment: Usual grumble: we could really use `\usepackage{isotope}`  to improve the typesetting when it comes to denoting nuclear reactions.

Comment: Great answer but I am not clear if the neutrino is necessary to cause the reaction.

Comment: @King-Ink How do you propose to conserve lepton number?

Comment: @King-Ink The spontaneous decay is $n \longrightarrow p + e^- + \bar{\nu}$. You can't avoid the presence of a neutrino of some kind or another.

Comment: How do you tell the difference between the spontaneous and neutrino caused decay in practice?

Comment: On an individual reaction basis you simply don't (neutrinos are too hard to detect reliably). On a bulk basis you can try to measure the anti-neutrino flux from spontaneous decays. That's not easy and needs a large source (we typically use nuclear reactors, though the natural radioisotopes of the earth have been used as well).

Comment: If you significantly increased the neutrino flux on a C-14 sample and observed a decrease in halflife you could determine how many decays were induced.

Comment: @LewisMiller In principle, yes. In practice it would need to be a precision experiment and would still take one hell of a neutrino beam. The more so as you would need to generate a beam of energy comparable to the usual neutrino background which is on order of $1\,\mathrm{MeV}$ (being mostly solar neutrinos). Such a beam is not available at this time and not anticipated any time soon.

Comment: @LewisMiller the alternate experiment is put a lump of C-14 in a low neutrino bit of space and see if its half-life increases.

Comment: @King-Ink Shielding neutrinos is even more difficult than making an intense beam. That's a non-starter, while Dr. Miller's suggestion merely needs a heck of a lot of funding and some years of hard work.

Comment: It was partly in jest. That is the problem with neutrinos isn't it? They are nearly impossible to detect and even harder to avoid.

Comment: @dmckee  Thanks for the assessment.  I'm just a theorist with no understanding of the practical difficulty of my suggedtion.